# Google Sky Maps does not follow pointing direction. How can the sensors be calibrated?

Tags: sensors, calibration

I have a new Lollipop device (Moto G 2. Gen) and wanted to use Google Skymaps. This worked like a charm on my old device. Now the display is not following the movements of the phone in the right way.

I think this is due to missing sensor calibration. I am missing a corresponding item in the Sky Map menues and I neither could find it in the general settings. How can i calibrate compass and accelerometer on my Lollipop device?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean to physically wave the phone in a pattern of a three dimensional infinity symbol (or simply a figure of 8).  [This YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP3d00Hr14o) video gives a good demo.

Moto G2 has gyro in addition to what Moto G1 have. Hence it should work like a charm and the issue you are facing should be a calibration issue at a low level.

Comment: The video shows the calibration for an Iphone. How can i start the calibration process on my Android Lollipop device?

Comment: The app's help menu under troubleshooting just says so without saying from where it has to be started. In my case, after opening the Skymap when the obvious planetary objects like Moon are not correctly aligned, I use to this calibration process right in the Skymap screen itself and it worked quite well in my Moto G1.  I do not think there is an user interface/app/setting for initiating this process.